# Android. How to show Snackbar on dialog properly?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, snackbar

I am trying to show Snackbar at the bottom of the screen on my custom dialog. It has some views, but they are not really important. Also it is a transparent background here.

I have got this error when I try to show this dialog. But it was fine without Snackbar. AlsoI cn show snackbar properly on the normal/regular activity.

Could you please help me with this trouble? Thank you. I am just trying to create a feature for my application, I am even not a real programmer :)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.com.com/com.com.com.DialogActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51 in com.gennady.timetobus:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Binary XML file line #51 in com.gennady.timetobus:layout/design_layout_snackbar_include: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

Here is the code of my class. I use it as custom view dialog with transparent background.

```
class DialogActivity : Activity() {
    var selectedGreenTime: String? = null
    var selectedIsSunday: String? = null
    var selectedDirection: String? = null
    private var selectedReminderButton = 0
    private var mFirebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics? = null

    val TAG = "TAG__ ${javaClass.name}"

    private lateinit var binding: DialogReminderBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        binding = DialogReminderBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        this.window.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        val rootView = binding.rootView
        val layoutParams = rootView.layoutParams
        layoutParams.width = 260.toPx(this)
        rootView.layoutParams = layoutParams

        showSnackBarFault("Text for snackbar")
    }

    private fun showSnackBarFault(text: String) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinator), text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setBackgroundTint(resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.colorREDForText))
            .setAction("OK") {
                Log.d(TAG, "snackbar button pressed")
            }
            .show()
    }
    private fun Int.toPx(context: Context) = this * context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
}
```

Here is the code of layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootView"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Title Text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I deleted some not important lines of code, so hope ot is ok.